# fork tree C, child processes PID

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, pid

I have to implement fork tree [as in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcwW1.jpg).

```
               +----+
      +--------| P1 |---------+
     /         +----+          \
    /         /     \           \
 +----+   +----+     +----+   +----+
 | P2 |   | P3 |     | P4 |   | P5 |
 +----+   +----+     +----+   +----+
           /  \                /   \
      +----+ +----+        +----+ +----+
      | P6 | | P7 |        | P8 | | P9 |
      +----+ +----+        +----+ +----+
               |
             +-----+
             | P10 |
             +-----+
```

Output must return something like:

```
   P1: pid: 1337 ppid: 1336 child processes pids: 1338, 1339, 1340, 1341
   P2: pid: 1338 ppid: 1337 child processes pids: 1342, 1342... etc.
```

where the child processes pids are pids of every child process of PX, and I don't know how to go about it. Can you give me some advie? My code so far is below, it creates the tree correctly imo, the child processes are a problem.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <sys/types.h> 
   #include <sys/wait.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pidp1;
      int pidp2;



switch (pidp1 = fork())
{
    case 0:
        printf("P2: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        exit (0);
        break;
    case -1:
        printf("Blad funkcji\n");
        exit (1);
    default:
        printf("P1: pid: %d ppid: %d child processes pids: %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), pidp1);
        wait(NULL);
        switch (pidp1 = fork())
        {
            case 0:
                printf("P3: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                switch (pidp1 = fork())
                {
                    case 0:
                        printf("P6: pid: %d ppid: %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
                        exit (0);
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                        exit (1);
                    default:
                        wait(NULL);
                        switch (pidp1 = fork())
                        {
                            case 0:
                                printf("P7: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                switch (pidp1 = fork())
                                {
                                    case 0:
                                        printf("P10: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                        exit (0);
                                        break;
                                    case -1:
                                        printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                                        exit (1);
                                    default:
                                        wait(NULL);
                                        exit (0);
                                }
                                exit (0);
                                break;
                            case -1:
                                printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                                exit (1);
                            default:
                                wait(NULL);
                                exit (0);
                        }
                        exit (0);
                }
                exit (0);
                break;
            case -1:
                printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                exit (1);
            default:
                wait(NULL);
                switch (pidp1 = fork())
                {
                    case 0:
                        printf("P4: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                        exit (0);
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                        exit (1);
                    default:
                        wait(NULL);
                        switch (pidp1 = fork())
                        {
                            case 0:
                                printf("P5: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                switch (pidp1 = fork())
                                {
                                    case 0:
                                        printf("P8: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                        exit (0);
                                        break;
                                    case -1:
                                        printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                                        exit (1);
                                    default:
                                        wait(NULL);
                                        switch (pidp1 = fork())
                                        {
                                            case 0:
                                                printf("P9: pid: %d ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                                exit (0);
                                                break;
                                            case -1:
                                                printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                                                exit (1);
                                            default:
                                                wait(NULL);
                                                exit (0);
                                        }
                                        exit (0);
                                }
                                exit (0);
                                break;
                            case -1:
                                printf("Blad funkcji\n");
                                exit (1);
                            default:
                                wait(NULL);
                                exit (0);
                        }
                        exit (0);
                }
                exit (0);
        }
        exit (0);
}
}
```

Comment: try to split in functions, be careful, you overwrite the pid of child, how can the father wait for it to complete, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as how this is homework, I'll try to give you some pointers.

Wow, that's a lot of code! There might be an opportunity here to take some of the code and put it into a function.

The tree you've linked is a bit weird-looking (not symmetrical), and it starts counting at 1, which is annoying. Nonetheless, we could describe the tree with two arrays: the number of children for each process, and the first number of its leftmost child.

```
/* The number of children for P0, P1, P2, P3, ... */
const int num_children[] = { -1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };

/* The P-number of the first child for P0, P1, P2, P3, ... */
const int first_child[] = { -1, 2, -1, 6, -1, 8, -1, 10, -1, -1, -1 };
```

You should be able to recreate the tree from your picture using only this information, and without actually looking at the picture. (Really, do it - I might have made a mistake.)

Then you could write a function that takes a P number, and does the following:

- Look up the number of children we have to make in `num_children`.
- Look up the P number of the first child in `first_child`.
- Fork a few times, each time running our function in the child, with the right P number, and storing the child's pid in the parent somewhere.
- Output the line you're describing in your question. You've stored all the child pids already, so that should be easy.
- Wait for its own children to complete.

Launch the whole thing with `yourfunction(1)`.

The leaf functions do not have children, so they would wait forever. That means your program does not quit anymore. Ever. This is actually *good* news: it means you can use Linux tools like `ps`, `pstree`, and `htop` to make sure your tree has the right shape.

(The lines of output will probably be output in a random order - I hope that's okay.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your program is not really readable. I think that you should start using structural programming. i.e.

```
void p2() {
   exit(0);
}
void p3() {
    if (fork() == 0) p6();
    ...
    exit(0);
}
void p1() {
    if (fork() == 0) p2();
    if (fork() == 0) p3();
    ...
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
   if (fork() == 0) p1();
   wait();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to having common parent for all child then go for this code instead of writing fork() no of times :

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (fork()==0) {
            printf("child %d -> pid : [%d] and ppid : [%d]\n",
                   i+1, getpid(), getppid());
            break;
        } else {
            if (i==0) {
                printf("parent   pid : [%d] \n", getpid());
            }
            wait(0);    
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if you wish to having parent->child1->child2 i.e child2 parent is child1 like this sequence then go for this code :

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (fork()==0) {
            printf("child %d -> pid : [%d] and ppid : [%d]\n",
                   i+1, getpid(), getppid());
        } else {
            if (i==0) {
                printf("parent   pid : [%d] \n", getpid());
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or according to your requirement you can add some condition inside loop. Hope this will help